# Numerical integration of sharply peaking function: $\int_0^{1000} \exp(1000\sin(x)/x)\,{\rm d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion, statistical-mechanics, euler-maclaurin

$$ \int_0^{1000} \exp(1000\sin(x)/x)\,{\rm d}x$$

Solve this integral of a sharply peaked function without a calculator.

I was told to not do an expansion of the sharp function, but of its gently varying logarithm.  Once that was done I should then see a function that I can expand. Once expanded put it back into the integral for the result.

$$ \ln [\exp(1000\sin(x)/x)] \ $$
$$ =[1000\sin(x)/x)] \ $$ 
Now the expansion of $\sin(x)/x$:

$$ 1 -x^2/3! + x^4/5!+\ldots +(-1)^nx^{2n+1} / (2n+1)! $$

$$ 1000 \int_0^{1000} \sum (-1)^nx^{2n+1} / (2n+1)!\,{\rm d}x$$

$$ 1000 \int_0^{1000} \sum (-1)^n x^{2n+2} / (2n+1)(2n+2)!\, {\rm d}x$$

I don't understand why when I put the integral into wolfram I get an answer of $1.35\cdot 10^{433}$, however when I put the integral into my calculator I get an answer of $1.14\cdot 10^9$.

Comment: This looks like a problem made for [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method)

Comment: ...which should give something like $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{1000 \cdot \left|-\frac{1}{3}\right|}} e^{1000} \sim 1.35\cdot 10^{433}$ (the factor of $1/2$ because $x=0$ is the peak and only half of the peak is in $[0,1000]$)

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really sure how to do Laplace's Method, but I'll check it out. I'm a bit confused as to why I was asked to do an expansion not of the function, but of it's logarithm, which is supposed to be approximately Gaussian.

Comment: Try to look at the justification/derivation of Laplace's method in the link I gave which is basically what you are asked to do. btw you only need to do a second order expansion of the stuff in the exponential which would lead to $\approx \int_0^{1000} e^{1000 - 1000 x^2/6}{\rm d}x \approx e^{1000}\int_0^\infty e^{-1000x^2/6}{\rm d}x$  and the latter is a gaussian integral you probably know how to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at that and my notes on Sterling's formula and I'll give that a go.

Comment: I followed the derivation in the link you sent, but I don't understand how you got the -1/3 term in the denominator or the e^1000 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asked to do is to derive what is called [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method), which is a way of estimating integrals on the form $\int e^{Mf(x)}{\rm d}x$ where $M$ is some large number, for the special case of $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

As you have done we expand the $\log$ of the exponential in a Taylor series to second order
$$1000\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1000 - \frac{1000}{6}x^{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)$$
so your integrand close to $x=0$ is given by
$$e^{1000\frac{\sin(x)}{x}} = e^{1000 - \frac{1000}{6}x^{2} + \mathcal{O}(x^3)}$$
Note that we keep the Taylor series in the exponential, we don't expand the exponential itself as you seem to have done. Since the integrand sharply peaks close to $x=0$ most of the weight of the integral will come from a small region around $x=0$ so we can cut the Taylor series at second order which leads to

$$\int_0^{1000}e^{1000\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\,{\rm d}x \sim \int_0^{1000} e^{1000 - \frac{1000}{6}x^{2}}\,{\rm d}x$$

where $\sim$ here means that the ratio of the LHS and RHS is close to $1$. Since the integrand drops very quickly to zero for large $x$ we can extend the integration region to $\infty$ without making much of an error (in absolute terms) and we are left with a standard gaussian integral which is easy to evaluate using the standard formula. This will give you something like

$$\int_0^{1000}e^{1000\frac{\sin(x)}{x}}\,{\rm d}x \sim e^{1000}\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1000}{6}x^2}\,{\rm d}x = e^{1000}\cdot C$$

for some constant $C$. To give a rough (order of magnitude) estimate of this first compute $a$ such that $e^{a} \approx 10$ (i.e. find an approximation for $\log(10)$) and write $e^{1000} \approx 10^{\frac{1000}{a}}$ and estimate the constant $C$. Note that you only need to use rough estimates like $\pi \approx 3$.